# Visualize 2D embeddings with confidence intervals

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I'm trying to produce an image similar to this one[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDwkq.jpg): 
Here they plot a 95% confidence interval as an ellipse.

I've tried using seaborn and generated this[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLRhw.jpg):
But this is only a scatter plot and doesn't have the confidence interval. Any ideas on how I can do this?

My code so far:

```py
def plot_visualizations(data,labels):

    # Set style of scatterplot
    sns.set_context("notebook", font_scale=1.1)
    sns.set_style("ticks")

    # Reshape labels array into (# of labels, 1) array
    labels = np.reshape(labels,(labels.__len__(),1))
    # Add labels to data array for a (# of labels, 3) array
    data = np.concatenate((data,labels),axis=1)

    # Create the pandas DataFrame
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Dim1', 'Dim2','label'])

    # Create scatterplot of dataframe
    sns.lmplot(x="Dim1", y="Dim2",hue='label',ci=95,legend=False,
                   fit_reg= False,scatter_kws={"s":200, "alpha":0.2},data=df)
    # replace labels
    new_labels = ['0', '1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']
    # plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 0.5), title='', labels=new_labels)
    # plt.legend(loc='best')
    plt.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5), ncol=1,labels=new_labels)

    #plt.title(r'$\beta = 10^{-3}$', weight='bold').set_fontsize('14')
    plt.xlabel('Dimension 1', weight='bold').set_fontsize('10')
    plt.ylabel('Dimension 2', weight='bold').set_fontsize('10')
    plt.show()
```